# Locating bug in complex application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

This is going to be a very general question. I'm hoping to find some tool or trick within Visual Studio 2010 that I don't know about.

Long story short, I'm taking over a very big accounting application for a company; there is no documentation and comments in the code are sparse. Also I have no access to the previous developers. There is a bug they need fixed right away. Basically a negative number is appearing in the database and the number should be positive. Nobody has any idea where in the app the calculation is happening, or where the data is actually being written to the database.  Does anything jump out at anyone as far as figuring out what class/function is doing this? I could watch the database while stepping through every line of code but that could take days.

Comment: This is a bit too vague to give a specific answer, but have you tried "find" in VS to find the table Name, or the Column Name in question in the source? Once you've found the Column name / table name then search for usages of the method it's contained in - if it's in ORM then search for usage of the POCO's or similar - should be fairly easy to trace the usage this way

Comment: if your column is updated in an SP you can find the SP with this T-SQL      select * from syscomments where text like '%column-name%' AND (text like '%update%' OR text like '%insert%') once you've located the SP name then use find in VS to find where it's called from

Comment: Thanks. Part of the problem is that the data could be coming from a SP or trigger (there are hundreds) as opposed to directly from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer you are going to like to hear but if its repeatable, you could approach this like a binary search.

1. Step over each procedure until the value changes.
2. Rerun and step in the procedure that changed the value.
3. Goto 1.

**Pro**

- It won't take you days
- you don't have to think about it while doing it
- I would be surprised if you haven't found it after repeating this a few ten times.

**Cons**

- not fun to do at all.

Comment: Followup question: What is the best way for me to monitor the database column while debugging? I'd hate to have to keep refreshing/re-running a select statement every time I stepped into/over a new piece of code.

Comment: Depending on how much energy you are willing to spend on this, you could write a small (console) app or script that does nothing more than executing the select in a loop and shows a message box when a change has been detected. That frees you from having to refresh manually but be sure to set the granularity of the refresh to be smaller than your "stepping through the code speed".

Comment: Yeah I was thinking just a little app/script that returns the number of rows. Thanks!